# Notable theories on the far side of the moon pre 1959

Tags: astronomy

On October 7th 1959, the soviet Luna 3 probe took the first picture of the far side of the moon.

It has been known since ancient times that the moon was a sphere. It would have doubtless been observed that the moon always seemed to present the same face to earth. The back face would have been a complete mystery, and I imagine **suspect to much speculation.**

The moon's [libration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration) allows attentive astronomers to see up to 57% of the lunar surface. Nevertheless, the thought of the unknown on the moon's far side must have been very tantalising to many astronomers, in the same way the appearance of Ceres and Pluto was to us prior to 2015, if not more strongly so.

**Are there any interesting or notable historical theories on what the far side of the moon looked like or contained?**

[image]
[image]
Top image: Luna 3 first image. Bottom image: Lunar Reconnaisance Orbiter composite image.
Source: wikipedia

Comment: There were plenty of speculations about the Moon in general, starting with [Plutarch](http://mossdreams.blogspot.com/2018/01/plutarch-in-light-of-moon.html) and [Lucian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_True_Story), but none of them focused on the far side specifically. Verne has his projectile fly over the far side when it is unlit. It is not like we can see the near side that clearly either, especially without a telescope. And in turn, only the near side of the Earth is visible from the Moon, so to the scientifically minded there was no reason to expect that the far side was much different.

Comment: @Conifold I'd be shocked (!!) if 20th-century astronomers didn't have some guesses as to the density of meteor strikes on the far side.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I am sure they did, but crater density estimates do not exactly sound like "much speculation" over  "a complete mystery" :)

Comment: @Conifold "And in turn, only the near side of the Earth is visible from the Moon". Wrong, the Earth does rotate relative to the Moon.

Comment: Interesting question. I have been wondering if there were "Notable theories on Pluto pre New Horizons". What they found seems to have been mostly surprises. Should I Ask this Question?